# React NextJS consume data dummy

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

here I am having trouble retrieving data from dummy json.

So, I have data like this =

Dummy.json

```
[
    {
        "label": "Belajar dari Kegagalan",
        "description": "Jika menghadapi kegagalan, lihatlah sebagai peluang untuk belajar. Analisis penyebabnya dan cari cara untuk memperbaiki di masa depan."
    },
    {
        "label": "Pemasaran Efektif",
        "description": "Gunakan strategi pemasaran yang sesuai dengan target pasar Anda. Manfaatkan media sosial, pemasaran online, dan strategi offline seperti iklan dan promosi."
    }
]
```

Then, I took it using MAP

```
{Dummy.map((data) => {
                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            <p className="text-stone-950 text-xl font-bold leading-[30px]">{data.label}</p>
                                            <div className="w-[480px] h-[108px] text-neutral-500 text-xl font-normal text-left">
                                                {data.description}
                                            </div>
                                        </>
                                    );
                                })}
```

However, when I viewed it in the browser, the output was not what I expected. It should come out one by one like a carousel

[image]

Do you have a solution? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it is a data problem but more a CSS problem. With the css you provide (with Tailwind) you're data will just be printed one above the other like a simple list.